# split file by lines into many different files - name each file with index of original file

Tags: python, linux, pandas, split

I have a large .txt file that I wrote to file using

```
`df.to_csv(header=True,index=True,sep="\t") in python`
```

I would like to split that file into files of len(index) = 2, using linux:

```
split -d -a 10 -l 2 $FILE ./FILES/file_batch
```

However, instead of creating file_batch0000000001 through file_batch0000159800, I would rather create each file using the first index name from the two lines used from the original file.

e.g,

```
`FILEoriginal.head()
out[1]:#           col1   col2   col3 ...
   #index0      val    val2   val3 ...
   #index1      val4   val5   val6 ...
   #index2      val7   val8   val9 ...
   #index3      val10  val11  val12 ...`
```

to:

```
`ls ./FILES
index0
index2`
```

and

```
`vim ./FILES/index2`

`col   col2  col3
val7   val8  val9
val10  val11 val12`
```

I would like the script to have computational efficiency (time) be on the order of the linux 'split' function if possible. i.e., trying to avoid loops.

Comment: why don't you write your script in python? also what's the problem with loops, i would imagine the bottleneck would be disk io, not looping

Comment: I was hoping for a quick bash script

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want? I don't think there's anything to be gained by writing this in bash:

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 2)
   with open(i,'w') as f:
      df.iloc[[i,i+1],:].to_csv(df.index[i],index=False)
```